# Ploting data in 3d using Python

Tags: python, plot, 3d

I want to visualize 3d volume in python  ,the data I have is given like that :

```
Z| X1 X2 ....Xn | Y1 Y2 ...Yn
1  ..........................
2  ..........................
3  ..........................
.  ..........................
.  ..........................
```

I tried to find solution I found plotly ,matplotlib : but they give the possibility to use just one representation , otherwise for plotting volume they  use a formula

my question is there any solution to plot these data in 3d to visualize like a volume

Comment: Command-line however http://www.gnuplot.info/ can do some nice things. You could call from python. Someone has made a python library to do this however I am unsure whether I would use the library or just run gnuplot directly.

Comment: Thanks Abinav , I will try it